# Starting with an InputStream, use PDFBox to add a text image to the PDF and finish with the original InputStream variable

Tags: inputstream, pdfbox

I'm having some trouble understanding how PDFBox works so I'm hoping someone can help me out here. Here is my code:

```
InputStream content=null;
    try{
        content = document.getImageStream(1);

        //Add image of word "Approved" at specific x and y coordinate in PDF

        //Do more stuff with InputStream content
```

I already have a bunch of code below that uses that InputStream so what I would like to do is use PDFBox to "update" the PDF that the InputStream holds by adding a textbox at a given x and y coordinate and then still have the same InputStream at the end so I can continue doing stuff with it.

All I know so far is to create a PDDocument from the InputStream like this:

```
PDDocument pddocument = PDDocument.load(content);
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: More often than not `InputStream` implementations are read-only. Thus, you usually cannot simply update it. What kind of `InputStream` do you have?

Comment: Later in the code I use that InputStream to create a new document using this document's image content. But before I do that I need to alter the image by adding that textbox to it. I'm using a custom built class to represent the document and I just realized that I can call a method from that class that returns a byte[] of the raw image. If I can alter that byte[] with PDFBox I can then make my new document with the byte[] so that's an option

Comment: I believe that I can load a byte[] to a PDDocument, make alterations to that PDDocument, save the PDDocument as a ByteArrayOutputStream and then call toByteArray() to get the new and improved byte[]. Does that sound correct?

Comment: *"Does that sound correct?"* - Yes. But you can do the same if you start loading from the `InputStream` provided by your custom document class, either way you can get the *the new and improved byte[]* and *make your new document* with it. Whether it is better to start with the stream or with the `byte[]` depends on how the custom document class produces them.

Comment: There is no PDFBox code `document.getImageStream(1);`. The PDDocument class doesn't have such a method.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr In a comment the OP writes *"custom built class to represent the document"*. I assume `document` is an instance of that custom document class.